# Decode HTML-encoded characters with extended ASCII

Tags: php, decode, html-entities, extended-ascii

I have an XML with special Characters encoded as &#xxx; in it. As long as I'd output these characters to a browser, that would work fine as they're HTML-Encodings (sort of).
But I need to read the XML-File with `simplexml_load_string`, which results in garbage for certain characters, because they're in the extended ASCII-table.

For example:

`&#154;` translates to š - but when I try to use html_entity_decode, I get an empty character.

I tried almost everything from `iconv` to `mb_decode_numericentity` - nothing worked.

How do I convert those &#xxx; to the real characters???

[Edit]
I found this table http://www.ascii-code.com that claims the `&#154;` is an extended ASCII Character using ISO-8859-1
I'm confused...

Comment: Given your example that &#154; should decode into a š, you're not using utf-8 encoding but some iso. Personally I'd switch to utf-8, but that's besides the point. My guess is that you need to instruct html_entity_decode() to stick to your favorite encoding instead of taking the default as specified in php.ini.

Comment: Thanks Karel - I actually tried that, using every encoding supported by html_entity_decode() - but none of them worked :(

Comment: Sounds like a non-standard and/or possibly obsolete usage of HTML entities. Not sure if any standard PHP function can handle this. Perhaps you have to write a custom `preg_replace_callback` function or similar which decodes these particular code points.

Comment: It's definitely not standard. The XML is provided by some 3rd party company. I have no idea why they're doing this. Interestingly, when I add the '&#154' into the google search field, it translates it to the š - so if they can do it, why can't I? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently dealing with two different characters that look almost identical when printing:

- ['LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON' (U+0161)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0161/index.htm) actually encodes as `&#353;`
- `&#154;` corresponds to ['SINGLE CHARACTER INTRODUCER' (U+009A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/009a/index.htm)

I've found that none of my fonts or text editors handle the second one properly. So you most likely get a blank character for that precise reason.

The second one appears to be some kind of [weird control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) whose exact purpose escapes from my understanding:

> To be followed by a single printable character (0x20 through 0x7E) or
>   format effector (0x08 through 0x0D). The intent was to provide a means
>   by which a control function or a graphic character that would be
>   available regardless of which graphic or control sets were in use
>   could be defined. Definitions of what the following byte would invoke
>   was never implemented in an international standard. Not part of the
>   first edition of ISO/IEC 6429

It's worth noting that [character references in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-charref) use numeric codes from a fixed encoding (some UCS variant). If the author of the XML file doesn't follow this convention you'll be faced with either invalid XML (something that effectively prevents it from being parsed with an XML library) or valid XML that contains corrupted data (something that, at most, will require tedious post-processing).

Comment: Thanks Álvaro. But it should definitely convert to the first one (š) as it's part of a name with that character. As I mentioned in my edit, I found out that &#154; is part of the windows-1252 ASCII-Table. But even when I try html_entity_decode('&#154;', ENT_COMPAT, 'Windows-1252'), I get a blank output.

Comment: [You can't choose the encoding of XML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-charref). Whatever, don't trust rendered characters; use an hex editor or print data through bin2hex() instead (if you haven't).